# Insert string to url and redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, href, location-href

Is it possible to insert a stringi into url?
Lets say I want `www.domain.com/news` to insert language flag `de` between com and news

Comment: Interesting! no effort try, no code but up vote !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a full url string that includes protocol or you know the base url  or if this is all based on current `location` you can use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API

```js
const url = new URL('http://www.example.com/news');
url.pathname = '/de' + url.pathname;
console.log(url.href);

// using current page `location`
const pageurl = new URL(location.href);
pageurl.pathname = '/foobar' + pageurl.pathname;
console.log(pageurl.href);
```

Comment: I believe this answer should mark as accepted, because it makes sense, it work even URL is `http://www.example.com/news/some/blah/blah`

Comment: @Pedram right...no need to figure out index of `/` or try splitting things up and joining them yourself

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf` to find the `/` character position, and `slice` with `join` to break the string into an array and reconstruct it while inserting the 2nd string into this position:

```js
var url = 'www.domain.com/news';
var flag= 'de/';

var position = url.indexOf('/') + 1;
url = [url.slice(0, position), flag, url.slice(position)].join('');

console.log(url);
```

Comment: That's what I needed, now in case of redirecting, just use window location with new url variable right?